# Problems with the relationship of one to many

Tags: java, spring, swagger-ui

I have problems with the relationship of one to many, to relate I just want to use the user ID I do not want to create a new one, I put my code

```
@PostMapping("/createFavorite")
    public ResponseEntity<Favorite> createFavorite(@RequestBody Favorite favorite) {

        return new ResponseEntity<Favorite>(userServiceImpl.createFavorite(favorite), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

my entity Favorite is

```
public class Favorite implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "element")
    private String element;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_fk")
    User user;
```

in swagger i get this

```
{
  "element": "string",
  "user": {
    "email": "string",
    "id": 0,
    "life": "suspend",
    "name": "string",
    "password": "string"
  }
}
```

i do not want to create new user,
The user is already created, I just need to use your ID to reference it

Comment: Are you sure you want to use your entity class as the request body? Your exposing your table structure which might be a security issue

Comment: @Coder what is your solution, can you anwer me please

Comment: Why not create a favouriteDto and use it rather than using Faourite directly in the request? Is that the requirement?

Comment: @Coder i should use this PathVariable?

Comment: @Coder can i use PathVariable idUser and PathVariable nameFavorite?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a new user or retrieve any existing user and set in favorite object. If in favorite.user.id is present, it won't create a new user.

Even you should set Cascade to CascadeType.DETACH to avoid creation or updation of User object from favorite object. It will throw error if favorite.user.id is null instead of creating a new user object.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_fk")
User user;
```

Comment: can i use PathVariable idUser and PathVariable nameFavorite?

Comment: @asdww PathVariable are visible and is inappropriate here. Whenever we are creating or updating a whole db object, we send it in RequestBody as a POST request, so it won't be visible in request url.

Answer (score 2):

Your entity structure is fine. You have to retrieve the user from `UserRepository` and assign it in the `Favorite` entity. IMHO, please introduce FavoriteDTO class. So entity models will not be exposed.

#### FavoriteDTO.java

```
public class FavoriteDTO implements Serializable {
    private long id;
    private String element;
    long userId;
//getters and setters
}
```

Your service implementation should check the user availability and then assign it to the `Favorite` entity.

#### ServiceImpl.java

```
public void createFavorite(FavoriteDTO favoriteDTO) {
   Optional<User> optional = userRepository.findById(favoriteDTO.getUserId());
   if(optional.isPresent()) {
       Favorite favorite = new Favorite();

       favorite.setUser(optional.get());
       favoriteRepository.save(favorite);
   }
}
```

Your updated swagger request json like below

```
{
  "element": "string",
  "userId": long 
}
```

Comment: but in swagger show this  "user": {
    "email": "string",
    "id": 0,
    "life": "suspend",
    "name": "string",
    "password": "string"
  },

Comment: i have this structure controller->services->repository, in the controller i should fill the fields or in service?

Comment: That's is correct. Because we have defined the user object in the Favorite class. If you don't want to define user object in FavoriteDTO, you can define userId field.

Comment: can you give me an example of your second option

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve your **existing** user and put it there as the favorite.user object (assign it). That way, it will work.

I am not very clear with your swagger specification. Are you using some kind of json schema?

Comment: can i use PathVariable idUser and PathVariable nameFavorite?